# 100% width images horizontally scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

how i can fix  horizontally scroll? :/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Navbar
        
            
            
                
                    Link
                
                
                    Link
                
            
            
            
                
                    Link
                
                
                    Link

```
<section class="boxes">
    <div class="container-fluid pl-0 pr-0">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="box col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d22wsyl1zemnyu.cloudfront.net/images/frontendfront-logo-share.png"></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.wearedigitalalchemy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/backend.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evkuw4zd/

Comment: You should explain what "fix horizontally scroll" means so your question is easier to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pl-0 pr-0` to `box col-lg-6` and delete  `pl-0 pr-0` from `container-fluid`

```
<section class="boxes">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="box col-lg-6 pl-0 pr-0"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d22wsyl1zemnyu.cloudfront.net/images/frontendfront-logo-share.png"></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-6 pl-0 pr-0"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.wearedigitalalchemy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/backend.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!-- Navbar Left -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Navbar Right -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<section class="boxes">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="box col-lg-6 pl-0 pr-0"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d22wsyl1zemnyu.cloudfront.net/images/frontendfront-logo-share.png"></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-6 pl-0 pr-0"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.wearedigitalalchemy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/backend.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Tether -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of `pl-0` and `pr-0` with the class `container-fluid` and it would work. Try this.

```
<section class="boxes">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="box col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d22wsyl1zemnyu.cloudfront.net/images/frontendfront-logo-share.png"></div>
    <div class="box col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.wearedigitalalchemy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/backend.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, its works but i need 100% width container, without paddings and margins

Comment: In that case, you can have the `pr-0` and `pl-0` and just add this style.
`.boxes { overflow:hidden; }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `no-gutters` on the row to remove the padding from the columns...

```
<section class="boxes">
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="box col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://d22wsyl1zemnyu.cloudfront.net/images/frontendfront-logo-share.png"></div>
            <div class="box col-lg-6"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://www.wearedigitalalchemy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/backend.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/1EgEJoRhmJ